# need clarification about GetCurrentProcess in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I freely admit that this is potentially a stupid question, but I need to be sure. When this grabs the current process, the "current" process is the one that called this function, right? I.E., the process that is requesting this information is the current process, correct? For example, if the process that is running this piece of code right now has a pid of 1, the Process object returned by this function will tell me it has a pid of 1, correct? I cannot possibly get any other process, correct?

Comment: This is correct don't be afraid of asking stupid questions, you did a good job of explaining what you wanted to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, as Micah commented. By using the GetCurrentProcess method you will only obtain information regarding the process that called it. You can view more information about the method on MSDN here: [GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx)

If you need to get information about a different process you can use [GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9.aspx).

Comment: Cool. Thanks to you both! I had already gone to the MSDN page for the function, I just didn't think its explanation was unambiguous enough.